# Scala with filter column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I get the error;

```
error: not found: value col
```

when I issue the command in Databricks notebook which I don't get the error when running it from a spark-shell;

```
altitiduDF.select("height", "terrain").filter(col("height") >= 11000...
                                              ^
```

I tried importing the following before my command query, but it did not help;

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

Where can I find what I need to import to use the col function?

Answer (score 0):

Found that I need to import;

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col}
```

to use the col function in Databricks.